# kotlin hibernate error "No property null found for type"

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, kotlin

I'm following a springboot tutorial loosely to build out my first springboot API.

I'm hitting an error when trying to run my repository test:

```
@Test
fun `savePattern - expect saved`() {
    val name = "test pattern"
    val chunkSize = 8
    val rows = 8
    val columns = 8
    val frame = Frame(listOf(1, 0, 1))
    val pattern = Pattern(name, rows, columns, chunkSize, setOf(frame))
    entityManager.persist(pattern)
    entityManager.flush()

    val found = patternRepository.findByIdOrNull(pattern.id)

    assertThat(pattern).isEqualTo(found)

}
```

With the repository interface:

```
interface PatternRepository : CrudRepository<Pattern, Long> {
    fun findByIdOrNull(id: Long?): Pattern?
}
```

And my entity Pattern:

```
@Entity
class Pattern(
    var name: String,
    var rows: Int,
    var columns: Int,
    var chunkSize: Int,
    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Pattern::class) var frames: Set<Frame>,
    @Id @GeneratedValue var id: Long? = null
)
```

And related entity Frame:

```
@Entity
class Frame(
    @ElementCollection
//    @OrderColumn
    var data: List<Int>,
    @Id @GeneratedValue var id: Long? = null
)
```

When I try to fire the test, I get the error:

> Could not create query for public abstract com.lightinspiration.matrixanimator.domain.Pattern com.lightinspiration.matrixanimator.repository.PatternRepository.findByIdOrNull(java.lang.Long)! Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract com.lightinspiration.matrixanimator.domain.Pattern com.lightinspiration.matrixanimator.repository.PatternRepository.findByIdOrNull(java.lang.Long)! No property null found for type Pattern!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract com.lightinspiration.matrixanimator.domain.Pattern com.lightinspiration.matrixanimator.repository.PatternRepository.findByIdOrNull(java.lang.Long)! No property null found for type Pattern!

I know this error message is probably crystal clear for someone who's experience with kotlin and/or java, but it's throwing me for a bit of a loop.

It's saying there's no property null found for type `Pattern!`, but I'm not sure what `null` property it's referring to. Also, if I'm defining a method interface that could return null, why would spring be looking for a not null pattern (i.e. `Pattern!`, or am I misunderstanding what that means in the error?). Did I define something wrong in my code (I'm assuming I did :|)

## Update

Sorry if I gave the impression that I didn't look through the docs first. I realize I didn't provide enough information in my original post.

To give more context, the Spring guide that I'm following in the [persistence with JPA](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-kotlin/#_persistence_with_jpa) shows the following test example:

```
@DataJpaTest
class RepositoriesTests @Autowired constructor(
    val entityManager: TestEntityManager,
    val userRepository: UserRepository,
    val articleRepository: ArticleRepository) {

  @Test
  fun `When findByIdOrNull then return Article`() {
    val juergen = User("springjuergen", "Juergen", "Hoeller")
    entityManager.persist(juergen)
    val article = Article("Spring Framework 5.0 goes GA", "Dear Spring community ...", "Lorem ipsum", juergen)
    entityManager.persist(article)
    entityManager.flush()

    // looking specifically at this line
    val found = articleRepository.findByIdOrNull(article.id!!)

    assertThat(found).isEqualTo(article)
  }

  @Test
  fun `When findByLogin then return User`() {
    val juergen = User("springjuergen", "Juergen", "Hoeller")
    entityManager.persist(juergen)
    entityManager.flush()
    val user = userRepository.findByLogin(juergen.login)
    assertThat(user).isEqualTo(juergen)
  }
}
```

and notes that:

> We use here the CrudRepository.findByIdOrNull Kotlin extension provided by default with Spring Data, which is a nullable variant of the Optional based CrudRepository.findById. Read the great Null is your friend, not a mistake blog post for more details.

And when I looked up the underlying extension, it looks like it should, you know, look up the id or return null:

```
fun <T, ID> CrudRepository<T, ID>.findByIdOrNull(id: ID): T? = findById(id).orElse(null)
```

My assumption was that when I extended my `PatternRepository` with the `CrudRepository`, the built in `findByIdOrNull` extension would be added to my repository and could be used to look up the ID.

This is why I am confused by the error message. My repository is set up with the correct `T` and `ID` types and I'm calling `findByIdOrNull` with the id of the matching `ID` type, so I thought that would fire the underlying extension method. It's good to see more detail on how the JPA builds queries, but I didn't think the query building was the issue I was grappling with.

Comment: whether your pattern.id is null ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, so waking up today and reviewing everything I see what the issue is.

Like I said in the update to my question above, the `findByIdOrNull` is an extension function provided by spring. Where I messed up was conflating methods inherited through extension vs the extension functions that can be added after the fact.

My full original test file looks like this:

```
package com.lightinspiration.matrixanimator.repository

import com.lightinspiration.matrixanimator.domain.Pattern
import org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.TestEntityManager


@DataJpaTest
class PatternRepositoryTest @Autowired constructor(
    val entityManager: TestEntityManager,
    val patternRepository: PatternRepository
) {

    @Test
    fun `savePattern - expect saved`() {
        val name = "test pattern"
        val chunkSize = 8
        val rows = 8
        val columns = 8
//        val frame = Frame(listOf(1, 0, 1))
        val pattern = Pattern(name, rows, columns, chunkSize)
        entityManager.persist(pattern)
        entityManager.flush()

        val found = patternRepository.findByIdOrNull(pattern.id!!)

        assertThat(pattern).isEqualTo(found)

    }

}
```

*(sorry, should have posted the imports in the question, I was trying to keep the code slim for readability sake but accidentally left some of the key details out :/ )*

The `findByIdOrNull` method was part of the `CrudRepository` interface itself, yeah I would have inherited that method, but `findByIdOrNull` is *an extension function*, which means it's not part of the CrudRepository interface:

[image]

It's a function added after the fact. So, what's implied in the tutorial's test is that you're importing the extension function in the test case code itself:

[image: works]

After I figured this out i [went and looked for the tutorial source code](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-boot-kotlin/blob/main/src/test/kotlin/com/example/blog/RepositoriesTests.kt#L8) and found they do the same import :facepalm:.

It def makes sense in retrospect, though I'm still new to extension functions/methods so it wasn't the first thing that came to mind.

Answer (score 0):

When working with CrudRepository the SQL is generated from method names. In your case when you write `fun findByIdOrNull(id: Long?): Pattern?`, this translates to

```
SELECT * FROM pattern WHERE id = 'value' OR null = 'value'
```

Since there is no field with name ***null*** in your table you get the error.

If for example you wanted to search all the patterns with given `name` and `chunkSize` then you would define a method as following (see the use of And operator in method name)

```
fun findByNameAndChunkSize(name: String, chunkSize: Int): List<Pattern>?
```

I suggest you read [Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.details), there are lots of examples

Comment: This information is helpful, but it makes me realize I need to include a bit more information about the tutorial. Updating my question.